# Openssl 1.0.1g rpm build issues in linux

Tags: linux, openssl, rpmbuild

We are building rpm for openssl 1.0.1g for Redhat5.9 and Redhat 6.4

Steps followed:-
1-Download the openssl 1.0.1 g tar file
2-Created the following dir structure

```
/myrpm/BUILD
/rpm/SOURCES
/rpm/SPECS/
/rpm/RPMS
```

3-./config
4-make
5-make install

Our goals:-
-We need to change the soname and realname of the library and link it properly
-We also need fips enabled with openssl.
-Include these changed sonames to our rpm while rpmbuild

Currently the 
soname creates as libbssl.so and libcrypto.so
real name as libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0

But we required in following formats :- 
soname ->libbssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10
realname ->libssl.so.1.0.1g and libcrypto.so.1.0.1g

It was not properly linking the sonames with realnames and not including these libraries in the rpm while building through rpmbuild command.

We have changed the Makefile and Makefile.shared but we need some options in openssl.spec file which create and link the soname and realname and also include these libraries in our rpm as mentioned above.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
@PP

Comment: Why not use Red Hat SRPM ie. source RPM and compile it from there?

Comment: For those interested, here's the equivalent Debian/Ubuntu question: [Override Distro Package with Custom Package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395280/override-distro-package-with-custom-package).